# How to personalize a data with Firebase real-time database for Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase

I am using the Fireabse real-time database with Android Studio to make an app. In the app, I wanted to make the user able to bookmark (or follow) a specific item (a sports game in my case).

The data for the sports game looks something like:

```
{
    Games: {
               Game A: {
                           Team A: A,
                           Team B: B,
                           Score A: 0,
                           Score B: 0,
                           isFollowed: false
                       }
           }
}
```

Something like that. In my app, I changed the color of a `Star` icon whenever `isFollowed` is true. However, this is global, so it will be applied for other users too.

My question is, how can I personalize the `isFollowed` data and make it different for all users?

My current idea is to put a HashMap that has the unique key Id of the user as the key value and the boolean value as the value inside the 'isFollowed` data.

Is this a valid idea?

If not, please tell me if there is a better idea for doing this.

Comment: "My current idea is to put a HashMap that has the unique key Id of the user as the key value and the boolean value as the value inside the 'isFollowed` data."
In this case for every separate game you need to add extra column like against 1 user if there are five games that means 5 games against 1 unique id and there respective isFollowed boolean which is not a good approach

Comment: @SaraTirmizi Sorry. What is your answer?

Comment: tell me one thing from implementation's point of view ..are these games different for every user OR these games are coming from single db for every user?

Comment: @SaraTirmizi These games are same for every user. They are coming from a single db. Sorry for missing that point in my question.

Comment: Then one of the approaches would be using id of game and creating object in your User object class at backend containing game id and isFollowed boolean, upon following or unfollow you can simply update boolean against individual user... by default isFollowed should be false.
remove isFollowed from comman table since it is of no use as there are multiple users

Comment: So you are saying it's better to add the isFollowed on the user side instead of the game side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159476/discussion-between-sara-tirmizi-and-dawn17).